# Is it okay to remind users about benefits and services of using my website (features) while they are completing "sign up" form?

Tags: forms, user-behavior, users, signup-signon, features

Is it okay and not distracting to put some features beside a sign-up form?
What's the best solution for a sign-up form like this? Please help[image: a sign up form for a Persian job finding website]

I have translated the form for you to understand what it's about but the concept goes like this form here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any user will never sign up if he does not know what is there in the website for him. In case you think your site is too complex that a user will not be able to identify the complete potential; you can use an optional tutorial after the user signs up.

Comment: Thanks Krishna for the answer. i think i should design it in more attractive way :)